# Wrong class attribute - Emmet VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm using VSCode and I am learning React.

I have an issue with Emmet which is expanding class instead of className.

To give you an example, when I expand `div.test` I get:

```
<div class='test'></div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div className='test'></div>
```

Can anyone help me fix that?

Comment: What is your extension of file, jsx? And validate and switch to right file type in right bottom side of editor.

Comment: My extension was .js but switching to .jsx solved it, thanks!